# Polynomial Ring Degree functions

Tags: abstract-algebra

$f(x) = 3x + 2$, $g(x) = 2x^2-3$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$[x]. What is degree of $f(x)g(x)$? is it simply just the highest degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is of degree $1$: $f(x)=x$ (degree $1$) and $g(x)=1$ (degree $0$), so $f(x)g(x)=x$.